# Using Developer Sandbox for developers related business process

Tags: sandbox

I was not sure if creating a business process like release management(maintaining the release information) where developer can add information about every release, postdeployment steps and so on, be kept in developer sand box. Also, if this data is on a custom object which reside only on developer sandbox and never deployed on production. ? The developers may or may not have access on Production Org so I was confused if such a thing is possible and allowed in salesforce world

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly vague ask. If you're interested in release management for your of SF development project I would highly recommend an IDE (MavensMate, Force.com IDE) as well as some sort of source control system (e.g. svn, git).

Can you clarify further on what you mean by: Also, if this data is on a custom object which reside only on developer sandbox and never deployed on production?

If you have new custom data that is created on a Sandbox and is never deployed to production that's fine; however, the data will be lost if the sandbox is ever refreshed from the Production Environment. Similarly you *could* create new users for people who don't have access to Production (assuming you have the extra licenses), but they would also be deleted upon a Sandbox refresh.

Comment: Here is what I had in my mind - Create a new Object with Name ABC. The intention of the object is for all the developers to capture the release activities like what objects are updated as part of current release, what would be the post deployment activities to be carried out, who owns the tasks, status of the tasks, date to be completed. Every release I ask the developers to update these fields. Admin would then pick the information and carry out code deployment(manually). The entire object is never deployed on production. There is no intention of using source control system for now.

Comment: Yes, that all sounds like stuff that could be easily done with the available declarative framework;however, the object records, the metadata, etc, would all be lost if/when you refreshed the sandbox.

Comment: Got it thanks .. so from a compliance point of view its not an issue?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your development team size and development process overall, take a look at [Agile Accelerator](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000000ps3jEAA) - a used-to-be Salesforce internal app for development they had released to public. It might work with Chatter free licenses...